# Change Mac settings depending on situation

Tags: macbook-pro, display, settings, parallels-desktop, fullscreen

I use my mac as a lightweight laptop at college, but when I get home I plug it in to charge and plug in 2 external monitors and use it for more power use. Some things that really annoy me are application specific settings. For example, when I use parallels with just my laptop screen, I want the fullscreen to be OSX fullscreen (Where it goes into a new screen and I can 4-finger swipe between them). However when I'm at home on my triple monitor setup, I want it to use Parallels fullscreen (Where the screen goes fullscreen, but not the OSX way, the window literally takes up the whole screen.

Is there any way I can set up two different setting/config files for Parallels, one for when I'm on the move, and one for when I have external monitors plugged in?

Comment: Is using two login user accounts an option for you?

Comment: No. I just thought there'd be some bash script I could run in the background that would switch a settings file if I had external monitors plugged in